# Why does Wolfram Alpha not return a solution to this problem involving Floor[]?

Tags: equation-solving

Wolfram Alpha did not find the solution 
$$x=\frac{8}{7} , y=7$$

to the equations below. Why?

What can be done to expect more accurate results from Wolfram Alpha, in similar cases?

[image]

Comment: This is not the place to rant; if you have a serious question -- ask, if not send that as an email to support@wolfram.com

Comment: @Sektor I completely disagree that this is a rant. One of the basic things that one expects from this software is the accuracy. I am not going to send any e-mail, and will leave this question here, to see what community thinks, I think it is useful for others to see, and for me to know the explanation.

Comment: Just leave the question as "Why?" and take out "This is a simple problem. This is disappointing".

Comment: If I understood correctly, @Şektor is saying that if one has not-serious questions, they should be sent to support@wolfram.com?? Strange.

Comment: @VividD: It could also be helpful to present the symmetric system of equations, where WA provides the complete set of solutions.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Perhaps you can add a note to the bottom of the question. Feel free to do it. I dont think another screenshot is needed. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Wolfram Alpha, not *Mathematica*, as per the [help center](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @blochwave Fine, but why did you edit the question, and than voted for closing? Something is not right here.

Comment: @blochwave If you voted for closing for the reason you mentioned, I suppose you checked that this problem is not present in Mathematica, right?

Comment: It's not exactly "not present". In fact MMA 10.1 cannot find any solutions at all. `FindRoot` does manage to find something though. Thus, I reckon, Wolfram Alpha has somewhat of an edge here and the question should be closed as unrelated to Mathematica *per se*

Comment: That said, I didn't realize from the review queue (where answers aren't shown), that digging deeper helps. It doesn't contradict the claim, that this is more about Wolfram Alpha, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't expect a CAS to figure out everything for you. You need to give some hints:

```
Solve[x Floor[y] == 8 && y Floor[x] == 7 && x > y]
```

Better hint by indicating ranges of variables:

```
Solve[x Floor[y] == 8 && y Floor[x] == 7 && 1 <= x <= 10 && 
  1 <= y <= 10]
```

> `{{x -> 8/7, y -> 7}, {x -> 8/3, y -> 7/2}}`

You can also do it by redefining $x$ as $x+d$ for some integer $x$ and $d \in [0, 1)$:

```
Reduce[(x + d) y == 8 && (y + e) x == 7 && x \[Element] Integers && 
 y \[Element] Integers && 0 <= d < 1 && 0 <= e < 1, {x, y, d, e}]
FindInstance[%, {x, y, d, e}, Reals, 100]
```

This returns all six solutions:

```
{{-8, -(7/8)}, {-4, -(7/4)}, {-(8/3), -(7/3)}, {-2, -(7/2)}, {8/7, 7}, {8/3, 7/2}}
```

Comment: What does guarantee me that my hint will work?

Comment: Or, how to choose the hint that works?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I also added a subquestion to my question seeking such tips.

Comment: @VividD, see my update for possible solution.

Comment: I've added a solution which gives every possible answer (I think).

Comment: @PatrickStevens, very nice!

Comment: @PatrickStevens Beautiful! Hope it works so charmingly for similar cases, involving "floor" function.